# How to write an API in C# that does not return all the data in a table at once to the client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have some basic react.js knowledge. I need to write an API in C# that will pull data
from a table and display in a KendoReact data grid. I want to be able to do filtering, sorting and pagination.
The data in the database is over 8,000. I will be using redux as we use redux heavily. I feel the amount of data that is
8,000 is a lot. What will be the best way to write this so that I am not returning 8,000 records to the clientside?

Comment: You can do the filtering, sorting, and pagination on the server side instead. Without more details on your C# API it's pretty impossible to give a more informative answer.

Comment: I'm about to write the API but looking for a good  way to write this.

Comment: How are you getting your data? Are you using an ORM? If so, which one (EF Core? Dapper?) If not, will you be writing your own SQL? If so, what database provider are you using? How do you intend for the client to communicate the filter/sort/page spec to the server? The answers to all of these will affect how you implement this

Comment: I am using EntityFramework and will be writing linq to entities. The database is sql server. I want to bind the data in a kendoreact data grid on the client side. I think the kendoReact grid should be able to handle the sort.

Comment: let the client (react) handle the pagination... using react-query and its pagination capabilities..this should get you started:  https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/paginated-queries

Comment: @Mx313- Are you saying return all the data to the client and let react handle the pagination?

Comment: @Baba yes correct, well let react-query (https://tanstack.com/query/v3/) handle it

Comment: If you are using SQL, you can pass a page index and page size to your API calls, which you could convert to "OFFSET (page index -1 * pagesize) ROWS FETCH NEXT (pageSize) ROWS ONLY" in your SQL query

Comment: @Alexandre - I am using linq to entities